# Group with inside an array element using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

For example:

```
var a = new { Key = new[] {1, 2} ... };
var b = new { Key = new[] {2, 3} ... };
var c = new { Key = new[] {3} ... };
```

I want a LINQ query that will get the result below, after `new [] {a, b, c}.GroupByWithArray(x => x.Key)`

```
Key 1: a
Key 2: a, b
Key 3: b, c
```

Comment: I think your question needs more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = new { Key = new[] { 1, 2 }};
var b = new { Key = new[] { 2, 3 }};
var c = new { Key = new[] { 3 }};

var result =
    new[] { a, b, c }.SelectMany(item => item.Key.Select(key => (Item: item, Key: key)))
                     .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
                     .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                                   group => group.Select(pair => pair.Item).ToArray());

var expected = new Dictionary<int, object[]>
{
    { 1,  new[] { a }},
    { 2,  new[] { a, b }},
    { 3,  new[] { b, c }}
};

result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected); // Pass Ok
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Can you please fix it?

Comment: And no matter which way I add in the missing bracket I can't get this output anything meaningful.

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry, missing bracket was before `GroupBy`

Answer (score 0):

This seems the most logical to what you want:

```
var a = new { Key = new[] { 1, 2 } };
var b = new { Key = new[] { 2, 3 } };
var c = new { Key = new[] { 3 } };

var values = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

var result =
    new[] { a, b, c }
        .Zip(values, (keys, value) => new { keys, value })
        .SelectMany(x => x.keys.Key, (x, key) => new { key, x.value })
        .GroupBy(x => x.key, x => x.value);

var output =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        result.Select(r => $"Key {r.Key}: {String.Join(", ", r)}"));
```

That gives:

```
Key 1: a
Key 2: a, b
Key 3: b, c
```

Now, I don't know what you meant by the `...` in your question, but if I just assume you meant that the list can be longer, then that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thank you. Sure the ... just means it's a meaningful object, the Key is not the only field. I want categorize these objects by Key.

Comment: And the output format does not matter. I just showed a example what the result should be after grouped.